# GraphQL Rails Update API getting `Types::ItemType#id`, which did not exist` error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I have two models Item and Artist, the relation is Item belongs to Artist and Artist has many Items.

app/models/item.rb

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

app/models/artist.rb

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I have created **update_item.rb** file inside **app/graphql/update_item.rb**

```
module Mutations
  class UpdateItem < BaseMutation
    
    type Types::ItemType

    
    argument :id, ID, required: true
    argument :title, String, required: true
    argument :description, String, required: true
    argument :image_url, String, required: true
    argument :artist_id, ID, required: true

    
    def resolve(id:,title:,description:,image_url:, artist_id:)
      Item.find(id).update!(title: title, description: description, image_url: image_url, artist_id: artist_id)
    end
  end
end
```

define its mutation type in app/graphql/types/mutation_type.rb

```
module Types
  class MutationType < Types::BaseObject
    field :update_item, mutation: Mutations::UpdateItem
  end
end
```

Mutatin which we have written in GraphiQL web UI is -

```
mutation{
  updateItem(input: {
    id: 13,
    title: "gfnm",
    description: "vcbnm",
    imageUrl: "fgehyerjfdbgh",
    artistId: 8
  }){
      id
      title
  }
}
```

it has been updated the record in the database but after that getting error in the rails server log below -

```
Failed to implement Item.id, tried:

              - `Types::ItemType#id`, which did not exist
              - `TrueClass#id`, which did not exist
              - Looking up hash key `:id` or `"id"` on `true`, but it wasn't a Hash

              To implement this field, define one of the methods above (and check for typos), or supply a `fallback_value`.
```

Could anyone please help me why getting the above error after updating the record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to these data in the GQL request,

```
{
   id
   title
}
```

it is expected that those fields (`id` and `title`) will be returned after the mutation is executed.

But there are no such fields defined in your mutation. What your mutation returns is the result of the `resolve` method, which is the result of the `update!` call, which is `true`. That's why you see the
`TrueClass#id, which did not exist` error. It cannot extract the `id` and `title` fields from `true`.

The fields that you want to be returned must be listed with the `field` method. The result of the `resolve` method should be a hash including those fields.

```
module Mutations
  class UpdateItem < BaseMutation
    
    type Types::ItemType

    argument :id, ID, required: true
    # ... The rest of arguments
    
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :title, String, null: false

    def resolve(id:,title:,description:,image_url:, artist_id:)
      item = Item.find(id)
      item.update!(title: title, description: description, image_url: image_url, artist_id: artist_id)

      {
        id: item.id,
        title: item.title
      }
    end
  end
end
```

---

Here is another suggestion. As the best practice, the result of the mutation should be the updated record:

```
module Mutations
  class UpdateItem < BaseMutation
    # ...

    field :item, Types::ItemType, null: false
    
    def resolve(id:,title:,description:,image_url:, artist_id:)
      item = Item.find(id)
      item.update!(title: title, description: description, image_url: image_url, artist_id: artist_id)

      {
        item: item
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Front-end:

```
mutation{
  updateItem(input: {
    id: 13,
    title: "gfnm",
    description: "vcbnm",
    imageUrl: "fgehyerjfdbgh",
    artistId: 8
  }){
      item { # requesting the updated record !!!
        id
        title
      }

  }
}
```

One more thing for you to figure out is how to handle error cases.